# Redux | Can't get an Axios response to dispatch to the reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I'm setting up redux in my React Native app and am struggling to get my response to dispatch to the reducer. I have confirmed that I am getting the response properly with the dispatch so the backend is working properly. I posted a lot of code below because I'm a bit lost, but my top three issues are:

1. I'm not connecting my component to the store properly
2. I didn't create the store correctly
3. authAction.js may be wrong altogether

Here's my code:

1)
In case I didn't connect right, this is how I connected it at the bottom of the component that uses the function:

```
export default connect(null, { signup })(ApprovedScreen)
```

2) store.js

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const inititalState = {};

const store = createStore(
        rootReducer, 
        inititalState, 
        applyMiddleware(thunk))

export default store;
```

3) authAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { LOG_IN } from './types'

export const signup = ({email, password}) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('myapi.com/signup', {email, password})
    .then(response =>dispatch({
        type:LOG_IN,
        payload: response.data.token
    }))
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

reducers/index.js (apparently this is automatically called rootReducer in the store)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { authReducer } from './authReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer
})
```

authReducer.js

```
import { LOG_IN } from '../actions/types'

export const authReducer = (state = {loggedIn: null}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOG_IN:
            console.log('the login reducer was activated!')
            return {loggedIn: action.payload}
        default: 
            return {...state}
    }
}
```

from my App.js file

```
const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

  export default () =>{
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
```

some relevant code from the file (Screen.js) where I call signup()

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { signup } from '../../actions/authAction'

const Screen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')  

  return (
    <View>
        <TextInput 
            value={email}
            onChangeText={text=>setEmail(text)}
            placeholder='Email'
            autoCapitalize='none'
            autoCorrect={false}
            textContentType='emailAddress'
            keyboardType='email-address'
        />
        <TextInput 
            value={password}
            onChangeText={text=>setPassword(text)}
            placeholder='Password'
            autoCapitalize='none'
            textContentType='newPassword'
            secureTextEntry={true}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitButton} onPress={()=>signup({email, password})}>
          <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>Create An Account</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

export default connect(null, { signup })(Screen)
```

Comment: does it log   this console.log('the login reducer was activated!') ?

Comment: @Renaldo Balaj unfortunately, it doesn't. Nor does the data post to the database.

Comment: can you post the file where you call signup

Comment: @Renaldo Balaj No problem, I just posted some relevant code from the file where I call signup.

Comment: but where are you actually calling signup function? All of the code you posted is import/export statements for signup.

Comment: button onClick={signup} <==        share this part

Comment: ah I see. I believe the portion where I call the signup function is firing properly because to test, I removed the dispatch portion from authAction.js and it correctly posted the data and returned the proper data. The issue comes when I add in the => dispatch => portion, I believe...

Comment: Just added the requested portion as well in case it is helpful, thanks all :)

Comment: if you check redux dev tools is anything making it into your store? I'm pretty sure your not making it into the store at all because your configuration is incorrect. nowhere are you exporting rootReducer

Comment: I don't have redux dev tools setup. But I doubt anything is because when I replace `.then(response =>dispatch({
        type:LOG_IN,
        payload: response.data.token
    }))` with `.then(response =>console.log(response.data))` I don't get a response at all. However, if I do `export const signup = ({email, password}) => {
    axios.post('myapi.com/signup', {email, password})
    .then(response =>console.log(response.data))
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}` I get the correct response.

Comment: @Oliver apparently if you name the combine reducer file 'index.js' and put it in the ./reducers folder it will know that this is the root reducer when you import rootReducer from './reducers - I got this info from 32:00 in this youtube instructional: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93p3LxR9xfM)

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj hopefully the additional context helps :) Thank you!

Comment: @Oliver - I put some more hours into this issue and found that the core of it was that for some reason I couldn't return a function within the authAction.js file. But by removing the "=> dispatch" and importing the store into the authAction.js file and calling "store.dispatch()" instead of just "dispatch()" everything worked fine. Thanks for your help :)